# Installing Openssl 1.0.2 on Ubuntu 19.04

Tags: qt, 19.04, openssl, ld

I have the source of an application written in Qt/C++ which I can try to build on Linux.

The system is Ubuntu 19.04.
The application requires some older versions of package, e.g. openssl-1.0.2.

I ran the following steps after install to set up Qt 5.11:

```
sudo su -
apt-get install build-essential
apt-get install qtcreator
apt-get install qt5-default
apt-get install git
apt-get install qtwebengine5-dev
apt-get install qtmultimedia5-dev
apt-get install qtscript5-dev
apt-get install open-vm-tools-desktop
cd /opt
wget https://www.openssl.org/source/openssl-1.0.2l.tar.gz  
gunzip openssl-1.0.2l.tar.gz 
tar xf openssl-1.0.2l.tar 
cd openssl-1.0.2l/
./config 
make install
ln -s /opt/openssl-1.0.2l/include/openssl/ /usr/include/openssl
apt install libleptonica-dev
apt-get install tesseract-ocr
apt-get install libtesseract-dev
apt-get install libvlc-dev
```

After the above steps, the application compiles in Qt, but building gave the `ld` error:

Unable to find libssl
Unable to find libcrypto

I think this is because these libs exist as static linked `.a` libraries, not as .so shared object libraries.

I tried build the `.so` as follows:

```
cd /opt/openssl-1.0.2l
./config shared
make install
```

This fails with:

```
make[2]: Entering directory '/opt/openssl-1.0.2l'
[ -z "" ] || gcc -fPIC -DOPENSSL_PIC -DOPENSSL_THREADS -D_REENTRANT -DDSO_DLFCN -DHAVE_DLFCN_H -Wa,--noexecstack -m64 -DL_ENDIAN -O3 -Wall -DOPENSSL_IA32_SSE2 -DOPENSSL_BN_ASM_MONT -DOPENSSL_BN_ASM_MONT5 -DOPENSSL_BN_ASM_GF2m -DRC4_ASM -DSHA1_ASM -DSHA256_ASM -DSHA512_ASM -DMD5_ASM -DAES_ASM -DVPAES_ASM -DBSAES_ASM -DWHIRLPOOL_ASM -DGHASH_ASM -DECP_NISTZ256_ASM -Iinclude \
    -DFINGERPRINT_PREMAIN_DSO_LOAD -o fips_premain_dso  \
    fips_premain.c fipscanister.o \
    libcrypto.a -ldl
make[3]: Entering directory '/opt/openssl-1.0.2l'
make[4]: Entering directory '/opt/openssl-1.0.2l'

/usr/bin/ld: libcrypto.a(gost_eng.o): relocation R_X86_64_PC32 against symbol `stderr@@GLIBC_2.2.5' can not be used when making a shared object; recompile with -fPIC

/usr/bin/ld: final link failed: nonrepresentable section on output
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make[4]: *** [Makefile.shared:169: link_a.gnu] Error 1
make[4]: Leaving directory '/opt/openssl-1.0.2l'
make[3]: *** [Makefile:357: do_linux-shared] Error 2
make[3]: Leaving directory '/opt/openssl-1.0.2l'
make[2]: *** [Makefile:310: libcrypto.so.1.0.0] Error 2
make[2]: Leaving directory '/opt/openssl-1.0.2l'
make[1]: *** [Makefile:109: shared] Error 2
make[1]: Leaving directory '/opt/openssl-1.0.2l/crypto'
make: *** [Makefile:287: build_crypto] Error 1
```

So the question is, how to get openssl-1.0.2 to produce the libssl.so and libcrypt.so on Ubuntu 19.04.

Comment: @steeldriver - Brilliant. The `make clean` and then `make install` did the trick. Thank you. If you add as an answer I'll happily mark it correct.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `./config --shared` command adds `-fPIC` to the Makefile's `CFLAGS`, which causes any C files to be compiled in a form suitable for linking into a shared library.

However, any files that have already been compiled to object code (`.o` files) during the default static build will not have had the appropriate `CFLAGS`. Attemting to link these files into a shared library will fail.

The solution is to run `make clean` to delete all the `.o` files before running `make install` with the new shared library config.